# Creating an element containing dynamically loaded HTML with angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

What I am trying to do is to load a specific HTML file containing some content when the user clicks on some link, then display it on the client's page at a specific place. Without angular I would have performed an AJAX request to get the HTML, then included it on the page, but it seems that I can't do it that way in angular. I am new to angular, so there might be quite a few things that I don't know or understand correctly.

What I am doing right now is the following : whenever the user clicks on a specific link such as this one : `<a href="#" link="defn:test" class="mot-clef" (click)="onClickMotClef($event)">identités</a>` then it calls that function :

```
onClickMotClef(event: Event): void {
event.preventDefault();
// On vérifie si le cadre n'est pas déjà chargé sur la page
let item = (event.target as HTMLElement);
var link = <string>item.getAttribute("link");
if (document.getElementById(link) == null) {
  /*
  Animation de chargement en attendant
  */
  //startLoadingAnimation();
  // On récupère le HTML du lien
  var filePath = "assets/cadres/".concat(link).replace(":", "-").concat(".html");
  // Pour rappel, le format de link devrait être prefixe:référence (defn:espace_vectoriel p. ex.)
  this.appService.getHTML(filePath).subscribe(
    (data: string) => {
      var temp = document.createElement("template");
      temp.innerHTML = data;
      let node = (temp.content as Node);
      item.parentNode!.parentNode!.parentNode!.insertBefore(node, item.parentNode!.parentNode!);
    }, // success path
    error => (console.log(error)) // error path
  );
  //Go sur l'ancre du
} else {
  // Le cadre est déjà charge sur la page, on y va directement
  //jump(link);
}
}
```

Here, the `appService` is a service that queries the link and returns the content of the file queried :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getHTML(lien: string) {
    return this.http.get(lien, { responseType: 'text' }).pipe(
      retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
      catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
    );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log('error');
    return throwError('');
  }
}
```

While that way of doing things inserts properly the div, the html code contained is not displayed correctly, it is actually displayed without any style. How can I make it such that the styles are correctly displayed ?

I believe that this is not really the "angular" way of doing things, I'm still new to angular. I have also tried another way, which would be to create a component whose template is `<div [innerhtml]="somevariable"></div>` and then dynamically create such a component, *at the right place*. The main issue I'm having is that I have absolutely no idea, how to create the component at the right place, which would be before the parent of the parent of the link. If this is a better solution than what I am attempting to do, then how should I go to create a component exactly where I want it to be, and to pass the string "data" to this component such that it will correctly interpret it as HTML ?

Comment: So there's a couple questions in here I see if I'm reading this right, you don't see your CSS applied to the rendered html you insert? Without reproducible example I'm guessing just adding [encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation) to the component decorator would clear that up. The second part can lead to a matter of opinion since there's multiple ways to accomplish the same as you stated. It just depends on how you want to organize the functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for, with ViewEncapsulation.None, now I'm getting the right styles for the element I'm adding to the page. That way I lost the styles I was applying to :host, but i solved the issue by placing the component inside a div, which i styled with what was applied to :host. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Chris' answer I was able to understand the actual issue I was facing, which was that style encapsulation was not correctly applied to the added HTML. All I had to do was to add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to the component in which I was adding new content.

Since I had some styling to the :host directive, which doesn't mean anything without ViewEncapsulation, then I had to place the component inside a div, and then style that div to get a style to the whole component.